# Spring MVC a href redirect to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, redirect, href

I'm not understanding how to set up an href to redirect to another jsp. This is what I have so far.

JSP with a href in it:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
       <body>
       <div align="center">
       <h1>${gradebook.gradeBookName} was created.</h1>
      <br> <a href="./">Home Page</a> <br> 
           <a href="/createGradeBook3">Add grades to GradeBook</a>
      </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The  href "/createGradeBook3" is the link I want to re-direct to.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/viewGradeBook3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String viewGradeBook3(Locale locale, Model model) 
{       

    return "viewGradeBook3";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following code snippet in your controller -

```
return "redirect:/path/to/jsp";
```

Or you may use another `URL` that has been mapped with a controller's handler method. In this case the redirected request will be handled by the controller's handler method.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.